# Change widget text in another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

Suppose I have ActivityA and ActivityB, also suppose that ActivityA is active. I need to:

1. Programmatically set a text of EditText in ActivityB from ActivityA
2. Launch ActivityB

Here's my code:

```
EditText res;
final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
final View resultView = factory.inflate(R.layout.ActivityB, null);

// get widget
res = (EditText) resultView.findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

// set the text
res.setText("foobar");


// create intent
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(i);
```

ActivityB starts, but without any text in `txtResult`. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before `startActivity(i);` in ActivityA

```
i.putExtra("myText", "someValue");
```

In ActivityB's `onCreate`

```
String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("myText");
myEditText.setText(str);
```